# Index all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Knowing that an indexed column leads to a better performance, is it worthy to indexes all columns in all tables of the database? What are the advantages/disadvantages of such approach?

If it is worthy, is there a way to auto create indexes in SQL Server? My application dynamically adds tables and columns (depending on the user configuration) and I would like to have them auto indexed.

Comment: first of all, if your query use not one but two or more columns, than it's better if you have two/more columns index. 
And second - indexes use disk space, so it's not free :)

Comment: also indexes makes your updating operations slower

Comment: Ocaso:  Not a duplicate.  The question you reference asks if it is a good idea to create 1 index that contains ALL of the columns in the table.  This question is asking if it is a good idea to create N indexes for each of N columns on a table.

Comment: You mean, "1 index for each of N columns..."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is difficult to imagine real-world scenarios where indexing every column would be useful, for the reasons mentioned above.  The type of scenario would require a bunch of different queries, all accessing exactly one column of the table.  Each query could be accessing a different column.

The other answers don't address the issues during the *select* side of the query.  Obviously, maintaining indexes is an issue, but if you are creating the table/s once and then reading many, many times, the overhead of updates/inserts/deletes is not a consideration.

An index contains the original data along with points to records/pages where the data resides.  The structure of an index makes it fast to do things like:  find a single value, retrieve values in order, count the number of distinct values, and find the minimum and maximum values.

An index does not only take space up on disk.  More importantly, it occupies memory.  And, memory contention is often the factor that determines query performance.  In general, building an index on every column will occupy more space than then original data.  (One exception would be a column that is relative wide and has relatively few values.)

In addition, to satisfy many queries you may need one or more indexes *plus* the original data.  Your page cache gets rather filled with data, which can increase the number of cache misses, which in turn incurs more overhead.

I wonder if your question is really a sign that you have not modelled your data structures adequately.  There are few cases where you want users to build ad hoc permanent tables.  More typically, their data would be stored in a pre-defined format, which you can optimize for the access requirements.

Comment: I would say that my concept is the same as the `master` database which contains tables that saves the structure of your databases and tables on the server. Those contain the data you need.

Comment: My database has standard tables which saves the configuration the user made. Depending on his requirements new tables could be created. I cannot guess his queries in design time

Comment: Actually, I believe most modern DBs store the index pages separate from the data pages, non continuous. While it does increase the total size of disk taken up, it would only affect memory, page loads and cache percentages if the DBMS used the index, aka read it into memory. An index that sits and is not used does not impact select performance.

Answer (score 17):

No because you have to take in consideration that every time you add or update a record, you have to recalculate your indexes and having indexes on all columns would take a lot of time and lead to bad performance.

So databases like data warehouses where there use only select queries is a good idea but on normal database it's a bad idea.

Also, it's not because you are using a column in a where clause that you have to add an index on it.
Try to find a column where the record will be almost all unique like a primary key and that you don't edit often. 
A bad idea would be to index the sex of a person cause there are only 2 possible values and the result of the index would only split the data then it will search in almost every records.

Comment: At least in Oracle, that is why [bitmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sharma-indexes-093638.html) indexes exist

Answer (score 11):

No, you should not index all of your columns, and there's several reasons for this:

- There is a cost to maintain each index during an insert, update or delete statement, that will cause each of those transactions to take longer.
- It will increase the storage required since each index takes up space on disk.
- If the column values are not disperse, the index will not be used/ignored (ex:  A gender flag).
- Composite indexes (indexes with more than one column) can greatly benefit performance for frequently run WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY or JOIN clauses, and multiple single indexes cannot be combined.

You are much better off using Explain plans and data access and adding indexes when necessary (and only when necessary, IMHO), rather than creating them all up front.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is overhead in maintaining the indexes, so indexing all columns would slow down all of your insert, update and delete operations. You should index the columns that you are frequently referencing in WHERE clauses, and you will see a benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Indexes take up space. And they take up time to create, rebuild, maintain, etc. So there's not a guaranteed return on performance for indexing just any old column. You should index the columns that give the performance for the operations you'll use. Indexes help reads, so if you're mostly reading, index columns that will be searched on, sorted by, or joined to other tables relationally. Otherwise, it's more expensive than what benefit you may see.

Answer (score 0):

- Every index requires additional CPU time and disk I/O overhead during
  inserts and deletions.
- Indies on non-primary keys might have to be hanged on updates, although an index on the primary key might not (this is beause updates typially do not modify the primary-key attributes).
- Each extra index requires additional storage spae.
- For queries whih involve onditions on several searh keys, e   ieny
  might not be bad even if only some of the keys have indies on them.
  Therefore, database performane is improved less by adding indies when
  many indies already exist.